# Eclipse/Tomcat7 - simple logging.properties to send all-or-nothing to console?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, logging, tomcat7

Here

[image]

I have added this

[image]

But my tomcat7 console still shows all this...

[image]

I flipped back and forth between SEVERE and ALL and noticed no difference in the console output.

What step am I missing?

Answer (score -1):

Set level to OFF
in your example
level=OFF

> Levels used for identifying the severity of an event. Levels are
>   organized from most specific to least:

```
OFF (most specific, no logging)
SEVERE (highest value)
WARNING
INFO
CONFIG
FINE
FINER
FINEST (lowest value)
```

Comment: You should explain why.

Comment: OFF has no effect, just like SEVERE or ALL.